# How to resize multiple resolution images to 2048x1024 in PIL?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have multiple images having different resolution like 1920x1080, 1920x764, 1280x964, 1280x720. I want to resize all this resolutions to 2048x1024 so that the images looks visually pleasing.

I tried direct resizing but it wasn't the good way.

How can I obtain the resolution while the image looks visually okay?

Answer (score 0):

This is a sampling issue which is almost never perfect. Personally I would try using the resize method that performs anti-aliasing.

Try the following:

```
img.resize((2048, 1024), Image.ANTIALIAS).show()
```

Next time please post the code fragment you are referring to and look into the PIL docs.

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html